# Can scipy.stats to calculate pmf automatically?

Tags: python, scipy

I have two questions.

1) I have an array like `[1,2,3,4,5,5,3,1]`. and I don't know which distributions it is. Can I use `scipy.stats` to calculate pmf,cdf automatically?

2)`scipy.stats` is just like a library of distributions? If I want to analysis data, I have to find one distributions or define one? I need to manually calculate some of data, like pmf. Am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, scipy.stats is not a library for telling you the distribution of data and calculating pmf and cdf automatically. Its a library for easing your tasks **while estimating** the probabily distribution. You have to explore your data and find which distribution which fits your data with least error ,which is the ultimate task and scipy.stats helps you achieving this.... **you don't have to reinvent the wheel** as they say by writing all the mathematical functions again and again.

Well, to answer your question in the comment, lets suppose you have a dataset, to get an insight and get a starting point for your analysis, what you'll do is plot the data in a historgram (which also shows **distribution** of data), now you can plot different distributions on the same plot using scipy.stats to get a feel of bestfit....

Check out this answer, it might help ya...

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best

Comment: Thanks, I'd like introduce myself first. I'm a java developer and interesting in statistics so I'm study it by myself now. I got a high school book and plan to use python do the exercise,  and it's ok for me to calculate pmf. and I start to study scipy.stats and try to make my exercise easier

Comment: what make me confuse is there's no wheel to calculate these values like pmf? I'm junior for python, and I'm not very familiar with the api document of python. I'm afraid of missing some thing here.